# Proving Set bounded vs unbounded

Tags: real-analysis

I know what a given set means to be bounded or unbounded, I'm a bit confused about how I would prove the set is bounded or unbounded. For bounded do I show an example of an upper bound and lower bound and have that be enough to prove it?

Two problems involving these:
Prove that the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: 10(x)^{1/2} - x > 0 \}$ is bounded.

Prove that the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: x^2 - 25x > 0 \}$ is unbounded.

Comment: Perhaps you could dominate MathJax before the world?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with how it works.

Comment: To show a set is bounded, you need to show that it is bounded above and below. To show a set $A$ is unbounded. You may show that $\forall b\in \mathbb{R}^+,\exists a\in A, s.t. \; |a|>|b|$.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first problem and prove that $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: 10(x)^{1/2} - x > 0 \}$ bounded, look at the condition for $x$ being in the set:
$$\begin{align}
  && 10(x)^{1/2} - x &> 0 \\
  &\implies& 10(x)^{1/2} &> x \\
  &\implies& 100x &> x^2 \\
  &\implies& 100 &> x
\end{align}$$
So $x$ is strictly bounded above by $100$. As [WorldDominator](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/213146/worlddominator) points out in the comments, because we had to divide by zero above, we should do a separate check to see if zero is in our set. Since
$$
  10(0)^{1/2} - (0) = 0 \ngtr 0
$$
zero cannot be in our set. To get a lower bound on our set, just notice that $x$ cannot be negative because there is a $x^{1/2} = \sqrt{x}$ in our condition. So
$$
  0 < x < 100
$$
The second one can be done similarly.

Comment: In other words: first figure out a more convenient expression for each set (a union of intervals, in this case); then determine whether they're bounded.

Comment: Isn't it proper to do x(100-x) > 0 though? Thanks for your answer, I thought this was the way to do it but I thought I was missing something.

Comment: What do you mean by "*proper*"? I don't quite see the motivation for expressing it as $x(100-x) > 0$.

Comment: Well as a part of factorization you get x = 0, which you would lose if you divide by x.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1 : $0 \lt x \lt 100$
Problem 2 : $x \lt 0 \lor x \gt 25$